# What is the equivalent of Ruby's "rake test" for project elfeed?

Tags: testing, elfeed

In a ruby/rails project, the "standard" way to run "the test suite" is

```
rake # alias for rake test
```

Some projects will mention (when there's a deviation)how to run tests in their README.

How do you run the test suite for this project?
https://github.com/skeeto/elfeed

Comment: Skeeto has two blog posts on precisely this topic: https://nullprogram.com/blog/2017/08/20/ and https://nullprogram.com/blog/2020/01/22/.  Archived: https://web.archive.org/save/https://nullprogram.com/blog/2017/08/20/ and https://web.archive.org/save/https://nullprogram.com/blog/2020/01/22/

Comment: FWIW, this question doesn't quite seem appropriate for SE.  Is there a way to modify the question so that it is more appropriate?  I believe the question boils down to, "How can I run Emacs tests using GNU Make?" or "How to manage an Emacs test suite?"  These are questions whose answers I'm interested in.  However, they too feel overly broad.

Answer (score 0):

`make check` is the GNU standard way to run "the test suite", and [elfeed seems to support it](https://github.com/skeeto/elfeed/blob/3.1.0/Makefile#L17).

https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Standard-Targets.html:

> ‘check’
>
> Perform self-tests (if any). The user must build the program before running the tests, but need not install the program; you should
>   write the self-tests so that they work when the program is built but
>   not installed.